Return End of String Between 2 Brackets - SSIS Derived Column Expression (SSIS 2022)
The difficulty of extracting the error column name in an SSIS data flow is widely recognized. To meet the requirement of minimizing scripting transforms/components, I cannot use a complex scripting solution to identify error columns in the dataflow. However, by utilizing two lines of C# that are well documented, I can obtain the Error Column description, which is the value shown in the Data Viewer—a string with the column name at the end, such as:
"OLEDB_DEST - Load Raw Dimension.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[ProductID]".
Below is my code in the ProcessInputRow method
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    // Get the error description 
    Row.ErrorDescription = this.ComponentMetaData.GetErrorDescription(Row.ErrorCode);
    // Get the error column name  
    IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
    Row.ErrorColumnName = componentMetaData.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);

}

I am seeking a method to use the Derived Column transformation to consistently extract the string between the last two brackets, which is the column name. Any help is appreciated.
Data viewer image
Thank you!
I've tried using SUBSTRING AND FINDSTRING but without success.

You can add a couple of more lines to the script that you are using to extract the ErrorColumn - Description which will be simpler than using a derived column:
IDTSComponentMetaData130 componentMetaData130 = this.ComponentMetaData as IDTSComponentMetaData130;
string errorColumn = componentMetaData130.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn);
int start = errorColumn.LastIndexOf('[') + 1;
int end = errorColumn.LastIndexOf(']');
Row.ErrorColumnName = errorColumn.Substring(start, end - start);

EDIT: Adding screenshots for clarification:

Configure source component to redirect rows to script component (transformation)



In script component, select ErrorColumn so we can get the source id.



Add a column to the output for ErrorColumnName


4.The ProcessInputRow method should look like this:


Final output should look like this:



Hi Mark,
Thank you for your response.
I got an error that componentMetaData130 doesn't have a GetIdentificationStringByID method.

Hi Mark,
Thank you for your response.
I got an error that componentMetaData130 doesn't have a GetIdentificationStringByID method.
CS01061: object does not contain a definition for GetIdentificationStringByID...

@libpekin1847 oh shoot, what version of SSIS are you targeting?

I am on SSIS 2022 version

@libpekin1847 Good that you're on 2022.  To troubleshoot this, I'll add screenshots for the whole configuration.  Would you mind editing your question with the complete code in the ProcessInputRow method that you are executing in the script component?

Yes, that works. @MarkWojciechowicz that you!
One small tweak. I still got an error with the "componentMetaData130" method. However, "componentMetaData" worked just fine. smh

Hi Mark,
I get a Script Component Runtime Error when executing the Script Transformation.
Error: 0xC0047072 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: No object exists with the ID 0.
system.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0047072): Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0047072 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProcessInput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 inputID,

@libpekin1847 this error doesn't tell us much.  It would be good to get the error from the script transformation and write that to the log
